# android view php result json on android app

Tags: php, android, json

i try to change in my java code a result returned  from json php code.

There is my php file :

```php
 <?php
 mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
 mysql_select_db("database");
 $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ads WHERE id='1'");
 while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
 $output=$row['number'];
 print(json_encode($output));
 mysql_close();
 ?>
```

This code return : 123456

Now in my AppMainActivity; i want to display the output here > "DISPLAY OUTPUT HERE" :

```java
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    configMenu(true);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    interstitial = new AdController(act, "DISPLAY OUTPUT HERE");
    interstitial.loadAd();
```

I have try to add the line :

```java
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(json.getString("output"));
```

but i don't know now what i must to put ..

I have searching, find many codes, but none comes close to what I want

Thanks a lot